# No able to set rythm.home.tmp.dir

Tags: java, rythm

The Rythm engine generates some .java and .rythm files like the following ones:

```
C2a55796c_5c47_3ca0_8e52_3ce1aacbd450__R_T_C__.java
C2a55796c_5c47_3ca0_8e52_3ce1aacbd450__R_T_C__.rythm
```

They are by default put in the root folder of the application. I wanted to set the engine to put these files in the ./temp folder, hence, passed the following config items to the engine:

```java
Map<String, Object> conf = new HashMap<>();
conf.put("engine.precompile_mode.enabled", true);
conf.put("engine.load_precompiled.enabled", true);
conf.put("rythm.home.tmp.dir", 
        Paths.get("./temp").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString());
engine = new RythmEngine(conf);
```

But it does not take the temp path into account! How can I set it so that the files go into the temp folder right beneath the application folder?

Comment: What's your environment? say OS, rythm version, any containers e.g. servlet?

Comment: OS: Win 7
Java: 8
Container: Desktop application
IDE: NB 8.0.2
Build system: Maven
Rythm: 1.0-b11-SNAPSHOT
@green

Comment: Dear @green would you mind replying! I am still struggling with the temp folder. It works neither in the dev nor is prod modes.

Comment: @javadch have you tried to use `new File("./temp")` instead of  `Paths.get("./temp").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString()`?

Comment: @stuXnet yes, I tested it. It does not create the folder if not existing, and does not put the files there even when exists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how your environment is set up. I did a very simple test and it shows the temp directory is correctly used:
[image]

Comment: Hi @green,
I tested it with new File("./temp"). it does not work too. This is the config I use:

            conf.put("engine.precompile_mode.enabled", true);

            conf.put("engine.load_precompiled.enabled", true);

            //conf.put("rythm.engine.mode", "dev");

            conf.put("rythm.home.tmp.dir", new File("./temp"));

Comment: `engine.precompile_mode.enabled` is created for Play-rythm usage, don't use it if you are not running play-rythm

Comment: I removed `engine.precompile_mode.enabled` but did not change anything, then I removed  `engine.load_precompiled.enabled` 
Now it works. Thanks.